# When trying to get a webpage using Qt QNetworkAccessManager, It always returns ""

Tags: c++, qt, http-get, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I'm trying to get a web page using Qt and print it on the screen.The problem is it always prints "". It won't make it to the done SLOT. I don't know if there's something wrong with the connect(). The code gets compiled with no errors.
Trying not to use event loops yet.

Here's the code:

net.h

```css
#ifndef NET_H
#define NET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class net : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit net(QObject *parent = 0);
    void get_site(QString url);
    QString data;

signals:

public slots:
    void err(QNetworkReply *);
    void done(QNetworkReply *);

private:

};

#endif // NET_H
```

net.cpp:

```css
#include "net.h"

net::net(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void net::get_site(QString url) {
    QNetworkAccessManager man;
    QNetworkRequest request;

    request.setUrl (QUrl(url));

    connect (&man , SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) ,this, SLOT(done(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect (&man , SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) ,this, SLOT(err(QNetworkReply *)));

    man.get (QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
}

void net::done(QNetworkReply * reply) {
    data = QString(reply->readAll ());
}

void net::err(QNetworkReply * reply) {
    data = QString(reply->errorString ());
}
```

And main.cpp:

```css
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "net.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    net netobj;
    netobj.get_site("http://stackoverflow.com");
    qDebug() << netobj.data;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: "Trying not to use event loops yet." Well, there's your problem.  There's no way this is ever going to work without letting the event loop do its job.  Put breakpoints in your slots and see what happens.

Comment: But there are some sources that didn't use that.I guess they use apps quit slot.I'm not sure.I'm new to Qt.

Answer (score 1):

There are some major problems in your code. First you should have the `QNetworkAccessManager` as a class member in .h file :

```
class net : public QObject
{
    ...
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
};
```

Also you should not connect the `finished` signal to two different slots. Your `get_site` function should be like :

```
void net::get_site(QString url) {

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl (QUrl(url));

    connect (&man , SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) ,this, SLOT(done(QNetworkReply*)));

    man.get (QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
}
```

And you should manage the returned reply in the following way :

```
void net::done(QNetworkReply * reply) {


    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
       data = QString(reply->readAll ());
    }
    else
    {
       data = QString(reply->errorString ());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.But still the same problem. Seems I should wait to get the response using a event loop.I couldn't figure out any other way.

Comment: I don't know why it jumps to slot before the reply finishes.or why it finishes before the reply gets the content!

Comment: Does it return an error when `finished` is emitted? I.e does `data = QString(reply->errorString ());` line get executed?

Comment: No, it doesn't get to else block.just the     if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) block gets executed. So there is no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your QNetworkAccessManager instance goes out of scope at the end of your `get_site` function.  According to Qt docs, one QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt application.  Your object should persist outside the scope of that function, since it's likely the response will take longer to receive than it will take for that function to end.  Make the QNetworkAccessManager a member of your net class, instead of an automatic variable local to `get_site`.

Note that you also need to manage the lifetime of the QNetworkReply object, not by using `delete`, but by using `deleteLater()` or else you might leak memory.

Comment: Thanks. the problem still remains. Maybe there's a way to wait to get the response? I don't know why it jumps to slot before the reply finishes.or why it finishes before the reply gets the content!

Comment: If you catch and look at the error codes and error string Qt returns, it should tell you.  I'd edit the post to show you how, but Nejat wrote a new answer that shows how.  Can you post the errors you're getting?

Comment: Answered Nejat. There is no errors.It works fine using a event loop. So I guess the problem is just that it doesn't wait to get the response. But I don't know exactly why.